# Angular2 rc.6 Use pipe in component

Tags: angular, typescript

In the rc.5 I used to do in my component :

```
private myCustomPipe = new CustomPipe()
this.myCustomPipe.transform(...)
```

Since I did migrate the application however, I am having an error on new CustomPipe() (I did move the injection from my component to my module's declarations).

In app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomPipe],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea how to achieve this in the Rc.6 ?

Comment: "I did move the injection from my component to my module's declarations". How does that look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use it in code (component, service, ...) not only in the view then you need to add it to providers

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomPipe], // only for view
    providers: [CustomPipe], // to inject to components or services
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```